# Displaying XML files with XSL-files in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt

How to display all XML files in one folder? These files will be placed in a subfolder called "files" with the same structure and name, chapter-1.xml, chapter-2.xml e.g.

I'm thinking a PHP loop to display the content of each file, but the files are styled with both XSL-document and a CSS-document.

Is there any way to achieve this? Can you bind the XSL and CSS-document in the PHP-file, and then print the content of the XML documents with the styling and rules of the XSL-document?

Comment: So you want to loop through a series of XML files to be converted into a *single* page of HTML?

Comment: Correct, worked it out (see comment below) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output of an XML-file requires just 3 lines of PHP code (and the XML file with proper XSL Transformation script for HTML output, of course):

```
<?php
$proc=new XsltProcessor;
$proc->importStylesheet(DOMDocument::load("test.xsl")); //load XSL script
echo $proc->transformToXML(DOMDocument::load("test.xml")); //load XML file and echo
?>
```

You can pick the file names and wrap an loop around it with usual PHP code. The example comes from my answer for [XML Outputting - PHP vs JS vs Anything Else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946833/xml-outputting-php-vs-js-vs-anything-else/4948312#4948312)

Comment: Thank you - worked it out with the example from PHP.net:

`<?php
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('kapittel.xsl');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('filer/kapittel-' . $i . '.xml');

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
}
?>`